# How to retrieve an xml attribute in shell script?

Tags: xml, bash

Imagine I have variable containing an XML string in shell script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<smil systemRequired="pss6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language" 
                            xmlns:pss6="http://www.3gpp.org/SMIL20/PSS6/">
    <head>
        <meta id="meta-smil1.0-a" name="Publisher" content="OMA"/>
        <layout>
            <root-layout width="100%" height="100%"/>
            <region id="UP" top="0%" left="0%" height="50%" width="100%" fit="meet" backgroundColor="white"/>
            <region id="DOWN" top="50%" left="0%" height="50%" width="100%" fit="meet" backgroundColor="white"/>
            <region id="FULL" top="0%" left="0%" height="100%" width="100%" fit="meet" backgroundColor="white"/>
        </layout>
    </head>
    <body>
        <par index="0" dur="10" size="29201">
            <img src="b964bdb7-1756-4c41-b3ba-6b2aeb1f5f96" region="DOWN" fill="freeze" size="12473"/>
            <text src="test [url]" region="UP" size="10"/>
            <audio src="88f6111c-f260-4042-8366-76a9e4c44417" size="16718"/>
        </par>
    </body>
</smil>
```

I want to retrieve the src attribute values of the `<image>` and `<audio>` tags so I would expect the output as follows

```
b964bdb7-1756-4c41-b3ba-6b2aeb1f5f96
88f6111c-f260-4042-8366-76a9e4c44417
```

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: You need to use an XML parsing tool to parse XML data. [tag:xmlstarlet] is one.

Comment: [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath) is another tool. It uses the `XPath` language to parse XML. I find it in the `libxml-xpath-perl` package for my distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution that probably fits your needs (I assume the XML file is in `file.xml` rather than in a variable) :

```
cat file.xml | tr "<" "\n" | grep -E "^(img|audio)" | sed -Ee "s/^.*src=\"([^\"]+)\".*$/\1/g"
```

- `tr "<" "\n"` : ensures each HTML tag is on a separate line (the `<` is removed at the same time but it is not a problem as we want it to be removed at the end)
- `grep -E "^(img|audio)"` : only keep `img` and `audio` lines
- `sed -Ee "s/^.*src=\"([^\"]+)\".*$/\1/g"` : removes the string before `... src="` and after `"...` so that only the src content is kept (captured group #1 of the regular expression)

Once the `grep` command is executed, we get the following result :

```
img src="b964bdb7-1756-4c41-b3ba-6b2aeb1f5f96" region="DOWN" fill="freeze" size="12473"/>
audio src="88f6111c-f260-4042-8366-76a9e4c44417" size="16718"/>
```

And once the `sed` command is executed, we get the result you expect :

```
b964bdb7-1756-4c41-b3ba-6b2aeb1f5f96
88f6111c-f260-4042-8366-76a9e4c44417
```

Comment: Hacking at XML with sed and grep is just painful. Your code is brittle. What happens when "audio" and "img" appear in the text outside of tags?

Comment: I agree, I never pretended this solution to be robust : that's why i mentioned "_a quick solution that may fit the needs_". As far as I can see, XPath is never within easy reach in a bash environment. A `tr` & `sed` based solution can be a quick win if the XML format you have to process is stable. But if you have a better, quick & robust solution Robert, feel free to share ;)